# Emulating a generic Mifare USB peripheral device with RFID-RC522

Tags: arduino-nano, usb, rfid, terminal

## Hardware

#### Dev Board: Arduino Nano V3.0

[image]

#### Module: RFID-RC522 13.56 MHz

[image]

#### Cable: USB A - USB Mini B

[image]

---

## Configuration

#### Physical

[image]

#### Code

```
/*
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Example sketch/program showing how to read data from a PICC to serial.
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * This is a MFRC522 library example; for further details and other examples see: https://github.com/miguelbalboa/rfid
 * 
 * Example sketch/program showing how to read data from a PICC (that is: a RFID Tag or Card) using a MFRC522 based RFID
 * Reader on the Arduino SPI interface.
 * 
 * When the Arduino and the MFRC522 module are connected (see the pin layout below), load this sketch into Arduino IDE
 * then verify/compile and upload it. To see the output: use Tools, Serial Monitor of the IDE (hit Ctrl+Shft+M). When
 * you present a PICC (that is: a RFID Tag or Card) at reading distance of the MFRC522 Reader/PCD, the serial output
 * will show the ID/UID, type and any data blocks it can read. Note: you may see "Timeout in communication" messages
 * when removing the PICC from reading distance too early.
 * 
 * If your reader supports it, this sketch/program will read all the PICCs presented (that is: multiple tag reading).
 * So if you stack two or more PICCs on top of each other and present them to the reader, it will first output all
 * details of the first and then the next PICC. Note that this may take some time as all data blocks are dumped, so
 * keep the PICCs at reading distance until complete.
 * 
 * @license Released into the public domain.
 * 
 * Typical pin layout used:
 * -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 *             MFRC522      Arduino       Arduino   Arduino    Arduino          Arduino
 *             Reader/PCD   Uno/101       Mega      Nano v3    Leonardo/Micro   Pro Micro
 * Signal      Pin          Pin           Pin       Pin        Pin              Pin
 * -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * RST/Reset   RST          9             5         D9         RESET/ICSP-5     RST
 * SPI SS      SDA(SS)      10            53        D10        10               10
 * SPI MOSI    MOSI         11 / ICSP-4   51        D11        ICSP-4           16
 * SPI MISO    MISO         12 / ICSP-1   50        D12        ICSP-1           14
 * SPI SCK     SCK          13 / ICSP-3   52        D13        ICSP-3           15
 */

#include <SPI.h>
#include <MFRC522.h>

#define RST_PIN         9               // Configurable, see typical pin layout above
#define SS_PIN          10              // Configurable, see typical pin layout above

MFRC522 mfrc522(SS_PIN, RST_PIN);       // Create MFRC522 instance

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);                 // Initialize serial communications with the PC
    while (!Serial);                    // Do nothing if no serial port is opened (added for Arduinos based on ATMEGA32U4)
    SPI.begin();                        // Init SPI bus
    mfrc522.PCD_Init();                 // Init MFRC522
    mfrc522.PCD_DumpVersionToSerial();  // Show details of PCD - MFRC522 Card Reader details
    Serial.println(F("Scan PICC to see UID, SAK, type, and data blocks..."));
}

void loop() {
    // Look for new cards
    if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent()) {
        return;
    }

    // Select one of the cards
    if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial()) {
        return;
    }

    // Dump debug info about the card; PICC_HaltA() is automatically called
    mfrc522.PICC_DumpToSerial(&(mfrc522.uid));
}
```

*<sup>See: https://github.com/miguelbalboa/rfid/tree/master/examples</sup>*

---

## Goal

#### Generic USB-Compatible Mifare NFC Read/Writer

So, you can get these devices that just plug directly into your regular computer via USB, and basically function as an ordinary HID or peripheral device. I have various different ones from when I was investigating the security implications associated with CRYPTO-1 & MiFare Classic access control cards. They all basically work the same, and produce/dump the same standard output.

The thing is, I have little experience with Arduino, and hardware development in general. The Arduino USB Port is obviously used for serial communication with the IDE for programming the MEGA328P, and I can use the IDE's serial interface, plotter, etc. But it doesn't seem to want to play with any of the other applications (MiFare Classic Universal tooKit, etc.) that "just work" with the (unaffiliated) commercial/store-bought devices.

[image]

Comment: I would guess, that the commercial products expose a different interface to the USB host (the PC). On the Uno/Nano there is an extra chip, that exposes a virtual serial interface over USB. On the Uno it is possible to reprogram that chip, to on the USB interface, what you tell him (On Nano it might be impossible to connect to the correct pins because of the size. Haven't done this ever). Or you use an Arduino/Chip, which already has native USB support, like the Leonardo. Though I don't know, if you really would be able to imitate the Mifare interface

Answer (score 3):

You have to use Arduino Mini and Keyboard.h library which comes with arduino IDE. Arduino Nano does not have HID capable processor.

Try this with mini:

```
#include <Keyboard.h>

void setup() {
 // make pin 2 an input and turn on the
  // pullup resistor so it goes high unless
 // connected to ground:
 pinMode(2, INPUT_PULLUP);
 Keyboard.begin();
}

void loop() {
 //if the button is pressed send the message
   if (digitalRead(2) == LOW) {

     Keyboard.print("Hello!");

   }
}
```

I will build same thing now, just tested Arduino Mini and will add rc522 to it.

Comment: did you try it? how'd it go?